# Recycleview pestañea

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, programación-móvil

Quiero crear un chat como wsp para Android, pero mi RecycleView está parpadeando, creo que la forma en como actualiza su contenido no es eficiente. Si necesitan algún otro java me avisan. El servidor está en python y entrega un JSON con mensajes. Quiero que los mensajes se muestren desde abajo y solo se agreguen los mensajes nuevos y no se actualice todo el contenido del Recycleview. Soy bastante nuevo en Java, pero tengo experiencia en otros lenguajes así que agradecería una explicación.

```
package cs2901.utec.chat_mobile;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SimpleItemAnimator;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.lang.*;
import java.lang.Object;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ItemAnimator;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    public Activity getActivity(){
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message);
        String username = getIntent().getExtras().get("username").toString();
        setTitle("Chat con "+username);
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        getChats();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {Thread.sleep(5000); getChats(); }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                }
            }
        };
        Thread hilo = new Thread(runnable);
        hilo.start();
    }

    public void onClickBtnSend(View v) {
        postMessage();
    }

    public void getChats(){
        final String userFromId = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_from_id").toString();
        String userToId = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_to_id").toString();
        String url = "http://192.168.1.11:8080/chats/<user_from_id>/<user_to_id>";
        url = url.replace("<user_from_id>", userFromId);
        url = url.replace("<user_to_id>", userToId);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                url,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray data = response.getJSONArray("response");
                            int uID = Integer.parseInt(userFromId);
                            mAdapter = new MyMessageAdapter(data, getActivity(), uID);
                            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                           // mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        );
        queue.add(request);
    }

    public void postMessage(){
        String url = "http://192.168.1.11:8080/messages";
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
        final String user_from_id = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_from_id").toString();
        final String user_to_id = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_to_id").toString();
        final String content = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage)).getText().toString();
        params.put("user_from_id",user_from_id);
        params.put("user_to_id", user_to_id);
        params.put("content", content);
        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST,
                url,
                parameters,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        // TODO
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // TODO: Handle error
                error.printStackTrace();

            }
        });
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
        editText.setText("");
    }


}
```

Comment: Estás creando un adapter, cada vez que la data es obtenida, solo debes crear el adapter una sola vez. Intenta utilizar DiffUtil para notificar los cambios al RecyclerView, puedes ver muchos ejemplos en línea.

Comment: como debería hacer el refactoring?

Comment: El setLayoutManager y setAdapter, pásalo al onCreate y donde llega el resultado, utiliza DiffUtil o notifyDataSetChanged() para eso tendrías que utilizar mAdapter.

Comment: he intentado de todo pero no se muestran los mensajes cuando saco el madapter del onresponse. podrias ayudarme con el refactoring por favor?

Comment: el mData de que tipo es? tengo lo siguiente:
    public class MessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
        RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
        JSONArray mData= new JSONArray();
        public Activity getActivity(){
            return this;
        }

Comment: en el oncreate esto:             mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.main_recycler_view);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            mAdapter = new MyMessageAdapter(mData, getActivity(),Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getExtras().get("user_from_id").toString()));
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());

Comment: sigo atorado en, podrías ayudarme haciendo tu el refactoring? :c

Comment: me da error en el .clear(); y en el notifysetdatachanged();

Comment: vale, pero respecto a la logica sí estás 100% seguro de que está de forma correcta?

Comment: Si, es la lógica correcta para inicializar y notificar los cambios.

Comment: una pregunta: ese "return;" qué retorna?

Comment: el notifty setdata changed no sería para el adapter?

Comment: dale. ahora el error es que no se muestra nada en el chat

Comment: https://pastebin.com/adHJxmjK   asi me quedó

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo logré solucionar. Un abrazo

Comment: Si lograste solucionarlo, por favor agrega una respuesta valida (mira [answer]) o elimina la pregunta.